# Login com Facebook no Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, facebook, xamarin-forms

Estou desenvolvendo um Aplicativo usando o Xamarin.Forms e preciso usar o sistema de autenticação do Facebook. o que acontece é que quando faço o debug dele recebo um mensagem de erro dizendo:

> Não é possível carregar a URL: O domínio dessa URL não está incluído
>   nos domínios do aplicativo. Para poder carregar essa URL, adicione
>   todos os domínios e subdomínios ao campo Domínios do aplicativo nas
>   configurações do aplicativo.

O problema é que eu não sei qual URL eu deveria por nesse campo. Segue o código do pageRenderer:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;
using Xamarin.Auth;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using GrowBox.Views;
using GrowBox.Droid;

[assembly: ExportRenderer (typeof (FacebookPage), typeof(LoginPageRenderer))]
namespace GrowBox.Droid
{
    public class LoginPageRenderer : PageRenderer
    {
        public LoginPageRenderer()
        {
            var activity = this.Context as Activity;
            var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator(
                clientId: "1978274929116582",
                scope: "",
                authorizeUrl: new Uri("https://m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/"),
                redirectUrl: new Uri("https://www.facebook.com/connect/login-sucess.html"));

            auth.Completed += async (sender, eventArgs) =>
            {
                if (eventArgs.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    var accessToken = eventArgs.Account.Properties["access_token"].ToString();
                    var expireIn = Convert.ToDouble(eventArgs.Account.Properties["expires_in"]);
                    var expiryDate = DateTime.Now + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(expireIn);

                    var request = new OAuth2Request("GET", new Uri("https://graph.facebook.com/me"), null,
                        eventArgs.Account);
                    var response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
                    var obj = JObject.Parse(response.GetResponseText());

                    var id = obj["id"].ToString().Replace("\"", "");
                    var name = obj["name"].ToString().Replace("\"", "");
                    App.HideLoginView();
                    App.NavigateToMainViewPage();
                }
                else
                {

                }
            };
            activity.StartActivity(auth.GetUI(activity));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Coloque a seguinte **URL** no campo **URIs de redirecionamento do OAuth válidos**:

`http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html`

[image: Imagem mostrando a tela de configuração da aplicação no Facebook]